# Calculate number of unique values with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm a beginner with dplyr package in R and I want to create some indicators from a csv file.

I want to calculate, grouped by client, the number of rows that have CODEARTICLE = "COUPON"

Without dplyr package I retrieve the number of row

```
length(which(merge_all$CODEUNIVERS == "COUPON")) #Result 249056
```

When I use dplyr and I group by IDCLIENT I have 0 foreach client:

```
test <- merge_all %>%
   filter(year(TIC_DATE) == 2017) %>% 
   group_by(IDCLIENT) %>%
   summarise(
     NbCoupon = length(which(CODEUNIVERS == "COUPON"))
   )
```

Why I have only the value 0 and how can I have the real number of "COUPON" by client?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following. Filter on coupon and year, group by IDCLIENT and use tally to count the occurrences.

```
test <- merge_all %>%
   filter(year(TIC_DATE) == 2017 & CODEUNIVERS == "COUPON") %>% 
   group_by(IDCLIENT) %>%
   tally()
```

Comment: `count(IDCLIENT)` would be equivalent to `group_by(IDCLIENT) %>% tally()` if you want to shave off a line